# How can i pass the parameter i recieved to a http request body in Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I am having parameterized Jenkins Job. I am able to catch the value in a string parameter.

[image]

I wanted to pass this parameter in an HTTP request body.
[image]

But whenever I pass this parameter, it is going as a text. i am not able to pass the value the parameter is holding. I also tried passing as {{pathToWar}}, ${pathToWar}}. But everything was giving me the same result. Can anyone please help me on this

Comment: Try `${env.pathToWar}`

Answer (score 0):

To access parameterised variable you need to access by `params.<Name of your variable>`. You can use `params.PathToWar`

Comment: Can I mention parmas.pathToWar directly in the request body. will that work?

Comment: I tried passing as you mentioned in the request body. it didn't work. it is still taking as string